# Can the second code be shortened the way it has been?

Tags: java, if-statement

//Consider the following code:

```
    boolean rez = true;
    if( rez == true )
        System.out.println( "result is true!" );
```

//Compare it to the following code:

```
    boolean rez = true;
    if( rez )
        System.out.println( "result is true!" );
```

//What is the difference between the two? Are they both valid?

Comment: In Java, these are the exact same. But you rarely see the first one as it's pretty redundant.

Comment: Both are same and valid. Second is best way

Comment: @gjman2 - But Kepani says the first is prettier!

Comment: More computational time runs in the first example.

Comment: @user2930207 , not at all, try to google about it

Comment: @Tdorno While the byte code may differ slightly (depending on the compiler), I would be surprised if the JIT results were not identical.

Answer (score 0):

it is  both valid because  `if( rez )` would always return true you can check [here](http://codingbat.com/doc/java-if-boolean-logic.html) for more examples in java conditional statements :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes they are both valid. But the first is bad practice.

The difference is that `rez == true` is redundant.
It's like saying  `if(true == true)`, boolean values doesn't need to be compared like that.

Comment: I would not say that it is _bad_ practice to write `if (rez == true)`; one could reasonably argue that it's easier to overlook the negation when reading `if (!rez)` than `if (rez == false)`, making the latter preferable.  Regardless of your preference, you should apply it consistently.  I do not personally write such comparisons using `==`, but I know very seasoned developers who swear by it.  There is certainly nothing _wrong_ with it.

Comment: IMO every redundant code is bad practice. But I get what you are saying.

Comment: Yeah, this is one of those battles I gave up on fighting.  Now I just let them have their `==` comparisons :).

Answer (score 0):

An `if` statement takes only a single parameter, `1` or `0` (`true` or `false`).

The statement `rez == true` evaluates to `true`, which is all the `if` statement sees, a single true, meaning yes, do this.